# Is there any statistical test to confirm if a dependent variable converges to a value as the independent variable approaches infinity?

Tags: regression

I have a very large set with 40,000 elements, and the dependent variable appears to approach a value as the independent variable goes to infinity. Is there any test I can perform to confirm if this is true?

I have considered using a chi square independence test and a linear regression test, but I do not know if these are the most appropriate tests for this case. Can someone please help?